# Refresh entity after child records inserted in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am inserting child records that are associated with an existing parent record. How would I refresh the parent record to show all, including the newly inserted, child records?

`context.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, entity)` isn't working.

A more complete example of my attempt:

```
Location newLocation = Json.deserialize<Location>(json);
if (newLocation != null) {
    IEnumerable<string> zipCodes = Regex.Split(newLocation.zipCodes, @"[\s,;]+");

    // this verifies the new zipcodes against a table of all US zipcodes and returns matches 
    var newLocationZipCodes = _zipCodeRepository.match(zipCodes).Select(item => new LocationZipCode { idLocation = newLocation.id, state = item.state, zipcode = item.zipcode });

    // get the parent entity
    var domainLocation = _unitOfWork.locationRepository.getFirst(l => l.id == newLocation.id);

    // insert child entities
    if (newLocationZipCodes.Any()) {
        _unitOfWork.locationZipCodeRepository.insertAll(newLocationZipCodes);
        _unitOfWork.saveChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
    }

    // this isn't working
    _unitOfWork.refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, domainLocation);
    return domainLocation;
}
```

Here is a basic representation of the LocationZipCode class created by linq-to-sql:

```
public class LocationZipCode {
    int idLocation;
    string zipcode;
    string state
    EntityRef<Location> location;
}
```

And here is my refresh method in my UnitOfWork:

```
public void refresh(RefreshMode refreshMode, object entity) {
    _context.Refresh(refreshMode, entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of refreshing the context I changed the way I was inserting my child records into the database. So instead of...

```
_unitOfWork.locationZipCodeRepository.insertAll(newLocationZipCodes);
```

I'm doing this...

```
domainLocation.LocationZipCodes.AddRange(newLocationZipCodes);
```

So the updated code looks like so...

```
Location newLocation = Json.deserialize<Location>(json);
if (newLocation != null) {
    IEnumerable<string> zipCodes = Regex.Split(newLocation.zipCodes, @"[\s,;]+");

    var newLocationZipCodes = _zipCodeRepository.match(zipCodes).Select(item => new LocationZipCode { idLocation = newLocation.id, state = item.state, zipcode = item.zipcode });
    var domainLocation = _unitOfWork..locationRepository.getFirst(l => l.id == newLocation.id);

    if (newLocationZipCodes.Any()) {
        domainLocation.LocationZipCodes.AddRange(newLocationZipCodes);
        _unitOfWork.saveChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
    }

    return new Mapper<DomainLocation, Location>(new LocationMapTemplate()).map(domainLocation);
}
```